# Nodelet error while running turtlebot gazebo on kinetic

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am not able to figure out how install nodelet separately, i tried to look in cmake file as well but got confused. PS i am new to ros.

Is there any one who can help? with some defined steps?

error message "[ERROR] [1517220409.629230351]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing..
"

Please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281091/nodelet-error-while-running-turtlebot-gazebo-on-kinetic/) by [HassanM](https://answers.ros.org/users/33385/hassanm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-28**:
What do you mean by

> install nodelet separately

? Also, please update your question with a copy and paste of the error message and what you've attempted.

**Comment by [HassanM](https://answers.ros.org/users/33385/hassanm/) on 2018-01-29**:
@jayess, i am not able to attach screen here. Anyways i installed full desktop version of kinetic. followed guidline carefully. but now when run gazebo_turtlebot while initializing an error comes up that gmapping/nodelet is missing. I have been searching around but couldn't find the solution.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-29**:
The image posting issue is due to you not having enough karma. In this case it works out in everyone's favor because you should *copy and paste* the terminal output *not* post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> but now when run gazebo_turtlebot while initializing an error comes up that gmapping/nodelet is missing

Based on your last comment I believe you're running into #q274849.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0